# Бесконечное подключение к mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Код подключения(до этого все работало, так что вряд ли проблема в моем коде):

```
mongoClient.connect((err, client) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    dbClient = client
    app.locals.collection = client.db("usersDB").collection("users")
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("App starts on http://localhost:3000")
    })
})
```

Пытается долго подключиться и в итоге выдает следующее:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to <айпи адрес сервера>:27017 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (...\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:293:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      '<айпи адрес сервера>:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      '<айпи адрес сервера>:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      '<айпи адрес сервера>:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-kjxwbc-shard-0',
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

P.S. Сервер использую бесплатный, чисто для обучения, может там какие то ограничения на кол-во подключений в час?

Comment: Возможно здесь есть [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431996/mongooseerror-mongooseserverselectionerror-connection-monitor-to-52-6-250-2)

Comment: @Rudi спасибо, проблема была действительно в айпи адресе

Comment: На здоровье! :)